# Issue with spring profiles not being picked up by cloudfoundry

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry

I am encountering problems getting spring profiles to work with cloudfoundry. My profiles are not picked up by cloudfoundry's tomcat...

Here is my **web.xml**:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" metadata-complete="true">
    <display-name>kadjoukor</display-name>
    <description>Roo generated kadjoukor application</description>
    <!-- Enable escaping of form submission contents -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml classpath:META-INF/cloud/cloudfoundry-auto-reconfiguration-context.xml</param-value></context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Handles Spring requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>kadjoukor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml classpath:META-INF/cloud/cloudfoundry-auto-reconfiguration-context.xml</param-value></init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>kadjoukor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout><!-- TODO -->
    </session-config>
<context-param><param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name><param-value>org.cloudfoundry.reconfiguration.spring.CloudApplicationContextInitializer</param-value></context-param></web-app>
```

Here is the content of the **WEB-INF/libs** directory:

```
activation-1.1.1.jar                     67.8K
antlr-2.7.6.jar                         433.0K
aopalliance-1.0.jar                       4.4K
asm-3.3.1.jar                            42.6K
aspectjrt-1.7.0.RC1.jar                 113.5K
aspectjweaver-1.7.0.RC1.jar               1.7M
auto-reconfiguration-0.6.5.jar          693.3K
cglib-2.2.2.jar                         280.5K
cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar                   319.3K
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar             226.6K
commons-codec-1.5.jar                    71.4K
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar           561.9K
commons-dbcp-1.3.jar                    145.3K
commons-digester-2.1.jar                192.2K
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar             58.2K
commons-io-2.1.jar                      159.3K
commons-lang3-3.1.jar                   308.4K
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar                37.1K
commons-pool-1.5.6.jar                   98.1K
dom4j-1.6.1.jar                         306.5K
ehcache-core-2.6.0.jar                    1.3M
flexjson-2.1.jar                         79.2K
guava-11.0.2.jar                          1.6M
hamcrest-core-1.1.jar                    74.8K
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar      69.6K
hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar            3.0M
hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.9.Final.jar     416.3K
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar     100.3K
hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar     358.0K
httpclient-4.1.2.jar                    344.0K
httpcore-4.1.2.jar                      177.0K
imgscalr-lib-4.2.jar                     27.2K
jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar              226.7K
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.9.jar            762.0K
java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar                  18.1K
javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar                 618.5K
javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar                 643.9K
javax.inject-1.jar                        2.4K
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar                 16.9K
jets3t-0.9.0.jar                        527.1K
jmimemagic-0.1.2.jar                     44.5K
joda-time-2.1.jar                       557.1K
jsr305-1.3.9.jar                         32.2K
jstl-api-1.2.jar                         29.8K
jstl-impl-1.2.jar                       382.8K
jta-1.1.jar                              14.7K
junit-dep-4.8.2.jar                     213.2K
log4j-1.2.16.jar                        470.2K
mail-1.4.3.jar                          451.3K
mysema-commons-lang-0.2.4.jar            11.8K
mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar         771.4K
ognl-3.0.5.jar                          222.5K
oro-2.0.8.jar                            63.7K
prettytime-1.0.8.Final.jar               65.4K
querydsl-core-2.9.0.jar                 367.3K
querydsl-jpa-2.9.0.jar                   93.3K
slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar                      25.4K
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar                   9.5K
spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar            327.0K
spring-aspects-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar         68.2K
spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar          590.6K
spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar        834.0K
spring-context-support-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar     124.1K
spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar           842.8K
spring-data-commons-core-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar     215.0K
spring-data-jpa-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar       129.8K
spring-expression-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar     189.2K
spring-jdbc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar           391.6K
spring-js-resources-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar       4.3M
spring-orm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar            383.0K
spring-security-acl-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar      77.7K
spring-security-config-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar     198.9K
spring-security-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar     332.1K
spring-security-taglibs-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar      20.3K
spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar     245.2K
spring-social-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar     113.7K
spring-social-facebook-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar     117.2K
spring-social-web-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar      18.0K
spring-tx-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar             235.3K
spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar            609.7K
spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar         621.0K
thymeleaf-2.0.14.jar                    677.9K
thymeleaf-extras-tiles2-1.0.0-beta3-SNAPSHOT.jar      46.7K
thymeleaf-spring3-2.0.14.jar            161.9K
tiles-api-2.2.2.jar                      35.1K
tiles-core-2.2.2.jar                    157.2K
tiles-jsp-2.2.2.jar                      49.6K
tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar                  58.3K
tiles-template-2.2.2.jar                 23.9K
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar              46.3K
xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar                      1.1M
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar                     106.8K
xmlParserAPIs-2.0.2.jar                  76.6K
```

It seems **a cloudfoundry jar library is missing** from the above list. Can anyone please let me  know which one that is?

Also, what I am getting wrong that **could prevent spring profiles from working**?

Comment: Regarding the first point (missing jar library), it seems the jar is not missing; here it is: `auto-reconfiguration-0.6.5.jar`.

Comment: Are you pushing your app specifying the framework "Spring". If this framework is not specified, auto-reconfiguration (including setting the "cloud" profile) does not happen.

Comment: I am almost sure I am pushing my app specifying "spring".

Comment: Is it possible that you have META-INF/cloud in your app (or in one of the jars other than the auto config one)?

Comment: I do have a `META-INF/cloud` in my app actually... What should I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a package (or pseudo package like /META-INF/cloud) in more than one location on your classpath (e.g. two jar files) then depending on the order the class loader decides to load them, they can hide each other.  In particular this happens when using `classpath:/...` paths to load resources.  You can sometimes use `classpath*:/...` but in this case that option may not be open. The cloudfoundry autoconfig jar contains /META-INF/cloud and it is being hidden by your app.  The Spring framework runtime agent adds the `classpath:/...` path to your web.xml, so unless you want to add an explicit `classpath*:/...` the best thing you can do is move the stuff you have in `/META-INF/cloud` to a different location.